# Why is an action built from superfields guaranteed to be supersymmetric?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, action, superspace-formalism

Given a superfield (in 0+1 spacetime + 2 superspace coordinates)

$$X(t,\theta_1,\theta_2) = x(t) + \theta_i \psi_i(t) + \theta_1 \theta_2 F_{12}(t)\tag{1}$$
and given the standard supercharges represented as differential operators
$$Q_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i} + i \theta_i \frac{\partial}{\partial t},\tag{2}$$

an action

$$S = \int dt \int d\theta_1d\theta_2 \,\mathcal L\tag{3}$$
is supersymmetric if

$$[Q_i^{hilbert}, \mathcal L]\equiv Q_i( \mathcal L) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\cdots)\tag{4}$$

i.e. if the (differential) action of the supercharge is a total derivative. I've heard that any action built out of superfields and superderivatives thereof is guaranteed to be supersymmetric. But from these definitions, I don't see why. **In what way does the superspace formalism furnish actions which are guaranteed supersymmetric?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, one may show that the infinitesimal SUSY transformation $$\delta {\cal L}~\propto~Q_i ({\cal L}), \tag{A}$$
cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/438300/2451). Now $Q_i ({\cal L})$ is by construction (2) a sum of total derivative terms. (Note in particular that in [superspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace) the total derivative can be wrt. a Grassmann-odd superspace coordinate $\theta_i$.) Hence the infinitesimal SUSY transformation (A) is a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) for the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$.